# DrawString with origin left/baseline

Tags: c#, winapi, gdi

When I use `Graphics.DrawString(... myPoint)`  the left/ top of the first letter of the string is at myPoint.

Can I combine DrawString with win32 SetTextAlign to set text origin  `TA_LEFT|TA_BASELINE` or is there some .NET equivalent?

If I draw a Rectangle at (100,100) and a string at (100, 100) I want the string to be above the rectangle (not inside at the top/left corner)

Comment: Is your string only consisting in a single line of text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There does not seem to be a built-in way to do this (even calling the overload of [DrawString()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d3thd43b.aspx) that takes a [StringFormat](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.stringformat.aspx) and specifying `StringAlignment.Far` in its [LineAlignment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.stringformat.linealignment.aspx) property would only result in bottom-aligning the text if the rectangle you provide is tall enough).

You can, however, perform the computation yourself and modify the `Y` coordinate of your `PointF` accordingly. For instance, you could use the [Height](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.font.height.aspx) property of the [Font](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.font.aspx) class:

```
yourPoint.Y -= yourFont.Height;
yourGraphics.DrawString(yourText, yourFont, yourBrush, yourPoint);
```

Note the code above doesn't actually implement baseline alignment (the whole glyphs will stand above the original coordinate in `yourPoint.Y`). True baseline alignment would required the "tail" parts of letters like `p` or `y` to lie below that point. It could be implemented with something more complicated, like:

```
FontFamily fontFamily = yourFont.FontFamily;
FontStyle fontStyle = yourFont.Style;
yourPoint.Y -= fontFamily.GetCellAscent(fontStyle) * yourFont.Size
               / fontFamily.GetEmHeight(fontStyle);
```

Comment: And if you use Alignment instead of LineAlignment?

Comment: @LightStriker, that property controls horizontal alignment, so it won't help us here :)

Comment: Ah! Sorry, just noticed he want to draw OUTSIDE of the rectangle.

Comment: Note the discrepancy, FontFamily doesn't know anything about the point size of the actual Font.  So how can it return a usable GetCellAscent?  The unit isn't pixels like your code assumes.

Comment: @Hans, you're absolutely right, I read `device units` instead of `design units`. I will update my answer to use the font's `Height` property instead. Thanks :)